# purrr opposite of pluck (throw away element) + preserving list structure in pluck

Tags: r, indexing, purrr

Suppose there is a list as follows:

```
x <- list(a = list(a1 = 1, a2 = 2), b = list(a2 = 3, a1 = 4))
```

The positions/names are mixed in the sublists, and to pluck out the `a1`s from the list, I would do the following in `purrr`.

```
x %>% map(purrr::pluck, "a1")
$`a`
[1] 1

$b
[1] 4
```

To *throw out* an element instead of keeping it, I experimented a bit, and came up with the following (I threw out `a2` here).

```
x %>% map(purrr::assign_in, "a2", value = NULL)
$`a`
$`a`$`a1`
[1] 1


$b
$b$`a1`
[1] 4
```

In terms of plucking, I actually like the second style better---that is, to keep the list indexing structure as is, while returning only the elements that I want. So I would prefer that once I perform `x %>% map(purrr::pluck, "a1")`, I get the second result.

Alternatively maybe there is a better way of throwing objects out in `purrr` that I'm not aware of, so that the output styles of the two code (plucking, throwing away) would be consistent?

Comment: Not a `purrr` approach but `magrittr::extract` will also give the desired result  `x %>% map(magrittr::extract, "a1")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we need a consistent approach, use `keep`

```
library(purrr)
map(x, ~ keep(.x, names(.x) == "a1"))
#$a
#$a$a1
#[1] 1


#$b
#$b$a1
#[1] 4
```

and `discard`

```
map(x, ~ discard(.x, names(.x) == "a1"))
#$a
#$a$a2
#[1] 2


#$b
#$b$a2
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using `modify_at`, and proposing a more idiomatic way to do your first call :

```r
library(purrr)
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.5.3
x <- list(a = list(a1 = 1, a2 = 2), b = list(a2 = 3, a1 = 4))

# rather than x %>% map(purrr::pluck, "a1")
x %>% map("a1")
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 4
x %>% modify(modify_at,"a2", ~NULL)
#> $a
#> $a$a1
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> 
#> $b
#> $b$a1
#> [1] 4
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>